# Is it possible to use the preprocessor or compiler to create stubs from a header file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, preprocessor

When I am writing unit tests in C++, often I need to create some stub method definitions of free functions which are declared in a header file actions.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void action1(void);
void action2(void);
int action3(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Instead of creating the stubs in a separate file

```
void action1() {}
void action2() {}
int action3() { return 0; }
```

it would be convenient to define the stubs on the fly in the test code when including this header:

```
create_stubs(#include <actions.h>)
```

Comment: I don't think `extern` does anything on these declarations in either C or C++. Aside from that, is it ok to modify `actions.h`? It would be relatively straightforward to just conditionally define a macro with the stub function body in there.

Comment: No, that's far beyond C++ preprocessor capabilities. You need to generate the stubs. Various refactoring tools can do it for you, including those in Visual Studio.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, to simplify the question I remove 'extern'. No I do not want to modify actions.h because I want to avoid cluttering the header file with testing related code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the preprocessor to create stubs from a header file?

No, it is not possible.

Use another language to parse the header and generate the source file. Python, Perl, AWK or similar.

Comment: Any explanation why this is not possible?

Comment: `that's far beyond C++ preprocessor capabilities` ~ Eugene

Answer (score 1):

C++ preprocessor doesn't parse C++ code, it is a wrong tool for your task.

You may like to use your compiler to parse the header files and generate an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html), using which you can find function declarations and generate stub implementations.

Comment: Do you believe that the stub implementation can be generated on the fly during compilation?

Comment: @20knots Of course. Generated source files are a common technique. You can even generate machine code just-in-time in memory at run-time.

Comment: Any hints how the implementation of create_stubs() could look like?

Comment: @20knots Search for "clang ast tutorial", there are plenty.

Comment: Just-in-time compilation does not seem an option here since the linker is not satisfied because of the missing function definitions. The most promising option, I see,  is to register an additional pass using the [LLVM_environment]( https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/release/14.x/llvm/examples/Bye/CMakeLists.txt).